# function returns updated dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm learning dictionary
here is my coding

```
def IncrementalCount(dict,a,b):

     dict={}.fromkeys(b,0)#creat dict initializing the count to each of "b" to 0 

     for txt in a:
          if txt in dict:
             dict[txt]+=1

     return (dict)        
counts={}
counts=IncrementalCount(counts,"{hello!{}","}{#")
print(counts)
counts=IncrementalCount(counts,"#Goodbye!}","}{#!@")
print(counts)
```

it prints the outputas

```
{'}': 1, '{': 2, '#': 0}
{'}': 1, '{': 0, '#': 1, '!': 1, '@': 0}
```

but it has to print

```
{'}': 1, '{': 2, '#': 0}
{'}': 2, '{': 2, '#': 1, '!': 1, '@': 0}
```

please help me

Comment: but you are *resetting* keys to 0..

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the counts to 0 was the problem with your code. So do not do `dict={}.fromkeys(b,0)` but just initialize the **new** keys. Something like this:

```
def IncrementalCount(my_dict,a,b):
     dict.update({k:0 for k in b if k not in my_dict})
     for txt in a:
          if txt in my_dict:
             my_dict[txt]+=1
     return my_dict

counts={}
counts=IncrementalCount(counts,"{hello!{}","}{#")
print(counts)  # {'}': 1, '{': 2, '#': 0}
counts=IncrementalCount(counts,"#Goodbye!}","}{#!@")
print(counts)  # {'}': 2, '{': 2, '#': 1, '!': 1, '@': 0}
```

Comment: why not? What is the problem with it?

Comment: @siva please mark the answer as correct, since it solved your problem